# Dotting two vectors that are contained in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a way to dot two vectors that are included in a list? Let's say I have two lists that contain a couple of vectors

```
list1 = {{1,2,3},{2,4,6},{1,5,7}}
list2 = {{4,1,9},{1,4,3},{2,8,3}}
```

and I would like to take the dot product between each of the vectors and give out the result in a new list. This function `function[list1,list2]` would then do something like

```
{{1,2,3}.{4,1,9},{2,4,6}.{1,4,3},{1,5,7}.{2,8,3}}
(*
{33, 36, 63}
*)
```

Comment: `MapThread[Dot, {list1, list2}, 1]`

Comment: Or `Dot @@@ Transpose[{list1, list2}]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the obvious approach is to use [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread). However, if you have large lists of vectors, a faster approach is to rely on listability:

```
a = RandomReal[1, {10^5, 100}];
b = RandomReal[1, {10^5, 100}];

r1 = Total[a b, {2}]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = MapThread[Dot,{a, b}]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 == r2
```

> {0.021, Null}
>
> {0.187, Null}
>
> True

So, about an order of magnitude faster. If you want an even faster option, you might consider the internal, undocumented function `` NDSolve`FEM`MapThreadDot ``:

```
r3 = NDSolve`FEM`MapThreadDot[a, b]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 == r3
```

> {0.012493, Null}
>
> True

The internal function is about 2 times faster.